# Remove html wrapper in iframe in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I don't know how to remove the html wrapper in the iframe.

**An example:**

```
var content = '<html><body>A page</body></html>';
$('iframe').contents().find('html').html(content);
```

Even if it does not look like it in the developer tools, the above now have 2 html tags.

```
var html = $('iframe').contents().find('html html').height();
```

When using the above I get a height. When only using one `html` in the selector I just get 0. It proves that there are 2 html tags.

**How can I get rid of the html wrapper in the iframe?**

In my case I will not modify the `content` variable. It's fetched from elsewhere.

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
$('iframe').find('html').replaceWith(content);
```

But it gave me:

> Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#text' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you should use `document.write`:

```
var content = '<html><body>A page</body></html>';
var iframeDoc = $('iframe')[0].contentDocument; // jQuery is just for the example of course
iframeDoc.write(content);
```

See [-DEMO-](http://jsfiddle.net/2q73uof7/)

If you want to overwrite previous set content used with snippet before, you will need to call `iframeDoc.open();` before calling `iframeDoc.write(content);`. It doesn't really makes sense but it is...

Comment: Just before I saw this I tried `iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);` that seems to have worked. Do you know the difference to yours?

Comment: `contentWindow.document` should be `undefined`. Can you set a jsFiddle or any online example where it can be checked?  EDIT: oops, i misread `contentWindow` for `contentDocument`, my bad...  And it looks like regarding older browser, `contentWindow` as better support, so if it works for you, use it instead but i don't think there is real difference here

Comment: I added an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2q73uof7/1/ but for some reason my version is disallowed. It gives a hint that your version is better. It also have better jQuery support.

Comment: It says `document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle.`

Comment: @JensTörnell Just a typo in your jsFiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/2q73uof7/2/   `getElementById( '#iframe' )` instead of `getElementById( 'iframe' )`

Comment: Ahh. I've tested yours in a real environment and it's shorter, more jQuery syntax and works. I'll use that! Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, the true jq syntax would probably be `var iframeDoc = $('iframe').prop('contentDocument');`

Comment: That's even nicer! I'll use that! :) Thanks again!